# Ruby Array - quick way to count overlap

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, intersection, overlap

I am working with serialized array fields in one of my models, specifically in counting how many members of each array are shared.

Now, by the nature of my project, I am having to a HUGE number of these overlap countings.. so I was wondering if there was a super quick, cleaver way to do this.

At the moment, I am using the '&' method, so my code looks like this

```
(user1.follower_names & user2.follower_names).count
```

which works fine... but I was hoping there might be a faster way to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an exact Ruby equivalent, but in python there's a built-in type Set. You could add all the followers and then just grab the length/count of that. Someone else might know the ruby-way, and what sort of performance you can expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sets are faster for this.

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'
alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
user1_followers = 100.times.map{ alphabet.sample(3) }
user2_followers = 100.times.map{ alphabet.sample(3) }
user1_followers_set = user1_followers.to_set
user2_followers_set = user2_followers.to_set

n = 1000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report('arrays'){ n.times{ (user1_followers & user2_followers).size } }
  x.report('set'){ n.times{ (user1_followers_set & user2_followers_set).size } }
end
```

Output:

```
              user     system      total        real
arrays    0.910000   0.000000   0.910000 (  0.926098)
set       0.350000   0.000000   0.350000 (  0.359571)
```

Comment: I'm a little worried about the time that it would take to turn an array into a set.. is that negligible? my arrays are between 0-3000 in length.

Comment: No it isn't negligable; both conversions to set (1000 times) together with the actual intersection operation take about 1 sec on this antique laptop. But in a scenario where a user_follower is compared against multiple followers, you start to win time if you store the set (in memory) and the number of followers is greater then 1. In other words, don't convert twice.

Comment: Just ran some numbers... and it looks like using sets was actually slower, because just the converting to sets took so long. I think i might be able to change all of my data structures to serialized sets, at which point, it would be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the above is to use the '-' operator on arrays:

```
user1.follower_names.size - (user1.follower_names - user2.follower_names).size
```

Essentially this gets the size of list one and minuses the size of the joint list without the intersection. This isn't as fast as using sets but much quicker than using intersection alone with Arrays

Comment: It turned out to be VERY minimally faster (about 1/100000 seconds), but no matter how many times I run it, it is a bit faster.. so i gave you an up-vote =]